# Removing blank space next to App Logo (ActionBar Sherlock)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

Can someone tell me how to eliminate the padding to the left of the app logo???

Here's what im talking about http://s9.postimage.org/ksxjpx1e7/Untitled.png

You can easily reproduce this even with ABS Demos, by adding to `AndroidManifest.xml`

`android:logo="@drawable/icon"`

I even tried editing `abs__action_bar_home.xml` directly but somehow that damned padding is still there.

```
<view xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    class="com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView"
    android:background="#00ff00" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/abs__home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/abs__action_bar_icon_vertical_padding"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/abs__action_bar_icon_vertical_padding"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@id/abs__up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_marginRight="-8dip"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />


</view>
```

Comment: This padding is reserved for `up` icon. I don't think that it can be easily removed, because it would violate Android UI patterns.

Answer (score 8):

As one of the comments pointed out, the padding is reserved for the up icon. The padding is present even though the up icon is not being displayed (so that the logo doesn't move when you hide/show the up icon). Using action bar (and `ActionBarSherlock`) there are basically 2 ways how to remove the gap:

1.**Remove the up icon** 
The size of the up icon affects the left padding, if you put there a bigger image than the arrow is, the gap will be bigger. If you remove it the gap will be gone. Beware that removing the up icon might not bring the exact looks you wish. Up icon and logo are partially overlapped (the up icon has negative right margin) so removing the up icon (it actually sets the image to nothing, does not affect the visibility) might cause that the logo is partially hidden behind the left edge of the screen. 
To remove the up icon set `android:homeAsUpIndicator` to `@null`.

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@null</item>
</style>
```

2.**Hide home layout and use custom view instead** 
This way it's more work, but you can affect the result better. You would need to put the icon and the title into the custom view. To hide the home layout and show custom, you have to set `android:displayOptions` in the action bar style. And then set the proper custom view in the code (you can set it in styles too, but that way it's buggy).

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="displayOptions">showCustom</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showCustom</item>
</style>
```